# Rotate layer by layer two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

Problem is; User enter 2 inputs to create an 2D array which is row and column.
Then 2D array fill with Random numbers. After that user enter 1 more input which is rotate array how many times. Here is my problem i have no idea how can rotate numbers layer by layer.

[Photo of Rotation](https://pasteboard.co/IikDitZ.png)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RandomArray
{
public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.print("Enter number of row: ");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int rows=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter number of column : ");
    int columns=sc.nextInt();     

    int twoD[][]=new int[rows][columns];

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            twoD[i][j] =  (int) (Math.random()* 10) ;
        }
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < rows; k++){
        for(int l = 0; l < columns; l++){
            System.out.print(twoD[k][l] + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
   }
}


//For example:

//  Enter number of row: 4
//  Enter number of column: 4
//  It will print:
//  2 9 6 3
//  2 1 4 2
//  4 1 0 1
//  7 4 2 8

//If user enter 3 as a rotation number.It should be like this:
//  3 2 1 8
//  6 1 1 2
//  9 0 4 4
//  2 2 4 7
```

Comment: What do you mean by rotate? Please post an input, expected output and efforts you have made.

Comment: Ps: those `i`, `j`, `k` and `l` in your loops are local variables. So in your second nested loop you can also use `i` and `j` if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to rotate it clockwise. You can create another 2d array `rotated` (to temporarily store the rotated values). Then you loop over each row `r` and column `c`.

```java
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
        rotated[c][columns - 1 - r] = twoD[r][c]
    }
}

twoD = rotated
```

You can put this in a loop for the number of rotations.

Comment: You just added an anti clockwise example. Thid answer still works for that. I leave the challenge of figuring out the proper indices to you.